# Correct way to use __constant__ memory on CUDA?

Tags: c, cuda, constants

I have an array I would like to initialize in `__constant__` memory on the CUDA device. I don't know it's size or the values until runtime.

I know I can use `__constant__ float Points[**N**][2]` or something like that, but how do I make this dynamic? Maybe in the form of `__constant__ float*  Points`?

Is this possible? And possibly more important, is this a good idea? If there are better alternatives to doing it like this I would love to hear them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic Allocation of Constant memory in CUDA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/271273/dynamic-allocation-of-constant-memory-in-cuda). This topic has been also discussed at [Constant memory allocation and initialization](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/367449/cuda-programming-and-performance/constant-memory-allocation-and-initialization/).

Comment: That's exactly what I needed. If you make this an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it has been discussed in [Dynamic Allocation of Constant memory in CUDA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/271273/dynamic-allocation-of-constant-memory-in-cuda) and [Constant memory allocation and initialization](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/367449/cuda-programming-and-performance/constant-memory-allocation-and-initialization/), you cannot. As noticed in [Constant memory allocation and initialization](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/367449/cuda-programming-and-performance/constant-memory-allocation-and-initialization/),

> Constants are embedded into executable at compile time (that's why you have to copy bytes to addresses specified by symbols to set constant values at run-time ). So, you wouldn't be able to allocate constant arrays of different sizes for different invokations of the same compiled kernel.

The recommendation in [Constant memory allocation and initialization](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/367449/cuda-programming-and-performance/constant-memory-allocation-and-initialization/) was to use texture memory since

> Texture sizes can be set dynamically and they are cached.

If you are using a Kepler, my recommendation is to decorate array pointers by `const __restrict`. In this way, you will be able to dynamically allocate arrays and the compiler will arrange things so that the data will be automatically read through the texture cache at runtime.